# Improve fit by trend adjustment

Tags: time-series, trend, bias-correction

I have data of daily observations for 35 years and I have modeled data for the same period. The coefficient of determination ($R^2$) between them is zero (no correlation at all!).

I want to correct the bias of modeled data, particularly adjust the trend of the modeled data to improve the coefficient of determination. Can anyone please suggest any statistical technique to do that?

The data is daily rainfall for a selected area and the observation is from 1970-2004.... I got also climate model data for rainfall for the same area for historical and future period and I want to correct the data on a historical basis and then implement the parameter of that correction for future data..... but most bias correction such as quantile mapping correct the mean error and percent of bias not trend of data ... so I'm looking for method the can adjust trend of modeled data (bias correction)

Comment: Are you saying that the correlation between the actual values and the fitted values is zero? That would be strange. Or what kind of "modeled values" (if not fitted values) do you have? Also, if there is a linear trend in the data, you may include a variable that is linearly increasing with time, something like $(1,2,\dotsc,...T)$ where $T$ is your sample size. If the trend has some other shape, you could do an analogous trick.

Comment: Hi, yes r2=0 and the modeled data is rainfall data from projected climate model (not my model) and I have observed data for same period I want a bias correction technique to correct trend (improve r2)

Comment: What kind of bias correction are you talking about? Also, if the modeled data is uncorrelated with the real data, that sounds like a very bad starting point...

Comment: The data is daily rainfall for a selected area and the observation is from 1970-2004.... I got also climate model data for rainfall for the same area for historical and future period and I want to correct the data on a historical basis and then implement the parameter of that correction for future data..... but most bias correction such as quantile mapping correct the mean error and percent of bias not trend of data ... so I'm looking for method the can adjust trend of modeled data

Comment: Could you update your post with the details you have already included in the comments, and also write more about the model you are using? It is difficult to help you given the current level of details.

Answer (score 0):

If you are talking about a constant bias, I think that what you intend to do is impossible. Zero correlation means that the slope of the regression line between the two datasets is zero; changing the offset (+-constant bias correction) cannot correct the slope.

If you are talking about a slow-varying bias (i.e. trend, drift, smooth signal, etc.), you may want to investigate detrending techniques. First, you should guess what kind of trend you have, it can be a linear drift, a seasonal component (common in Earth science datasets), etc.. You can try moving average with different window sizes to reveal hidden trends; if you are familiar with signal processing you can take a look to wavelet decomposition.

Hope that helps.